# In a rigid rotor, are there "elegant" orientation coordinates that are conjugate to angular momenta?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, rigid-body-dynamics

I just was looking at the big bag-of-math wikipedia article on rigid rotors, and [the section on the Hamiltonian form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor#Hamilton_form) bugs me a bit since they are using Euler angles to represent the orientation. As a result the expressions seem to lack a certain elegance, and the canonical momenta are certainly not the angular momenta in this case. It got me wondering, can this be solved?

My question, then: is there some orientation representation system for which the canonical momenta $p_i$ actually *do* coincide with the angular momenta $L_i$?
I know that this is problematic and there may be no perfect solution, due to [the structure of the space of rotations in 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO%283%29). If there is no ideal solution, can we at least get a more elegant result than Euler angles by using a representation which treats all axes fairly (axis-angle or quaternion)?

Comment: Are you worried about making this "more pretty"? I am not sure that can be done for the general case. The system is not pretty and it has some very nasty properties (one of which is instability and chaos). Once we make the rotator symmetric (i.e. by choosing $I_1=I_2$, things look a little better.

Comment: Whenever the potential is velocity-independent, with a kinetic term of the form $T = \frac{I_{\mu\nu}}{2} \omega^\mu\omega^\nu$ the canonical momentum *is* the angular momentum.

Comment: @CuriousOne, indeed I am just looking for something "more pretty", especially something that can be used in the nasty case.

Comment: Nothing can be used in the "nasty" case. That one produces chaos. You can test it yourself. Throw a brick into the air around all three of its axes. Two rotations will be stable, the third one will tumble chaotically.

Comment: @CuriousOne Rotation about the intermediate axis is unstable, but it is not chaotic. In fact, the system is completely integrable (although with degenerate invariant tori at some points in phase space). Construction of the action variables conjugate to the Euler angles is sometimes referred to as the "Serret-Andoyer" construction.

Comment: I realize this was asked a long time ago now... but this is the sort of problem I'm tackling... I have this sort of pending question, which has my rotation space exploration tool... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759693/finding-the-parameters-of-curves-of-rotations-in-rotation-space  there's a lot of linearity to the curvature... it shouldn't be so impossible to simply rotate curvatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the potential is velocity-independent, with a kinetic term of the form $T = \frac{I_{\mu\nu}}{2}\omega^μ \omega^ν$, the canonical momentum is the angular momentum. What you have noted is that when the Euler angles are used as coordinates on $SO(3)$, the components of the momentum are not the Cartesian components of the momentum, and your question is whether it is possible to choose other coordinates on $SO(3)$ so that this is the case.

The answer to this question is no, and it has to do with that $SO(3)$ is not an Abelian group. What are the $\dot q^i$? They are vector fields on $SO(3)$. The Cartesian components of the angular momentum are the components with respect to the vector fields $R_x, R_y, R_z$ representing $x,y,z$ rotations. Because these don't commute, it is not possible to find coordinates such that $R_x, R_y, R_z$ are all coordinate vector fields.

Comment: I suppose the kinetic term does have that form however the moment of inertia changes with orientation. (At least, the moment of intertia seen from the nonrotating frame of reference where angular momentum is a constant vector.)

Comment: I just realized another reason that forbids the angular momenta to be the canonical momenta of the system. Their Poisson brackets against each other are nonzero, e.g., $\{L_x, L_y\} = L_z$. But always with a system of canonical momenta we must have $\{p_1, p_2\} = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters that they don't commute... if you approach the system from the base angle-angle-angle, many operations are simply additions, and every angle-angle-angle (basically a `ln(Q)` or natural log of a quaternion) has a valid unit quaternion projection... and yes, order of operations matters if you look at a specific step in the sequence of operations; but if they all happen in parallel, the order doesn't matter. (Makes IK solving very simple)